# Can I remove outdated file from makefile?

Tags: makefile

I'm not a C++ guy, so please bear with me. It seems to me that the latest [ddccontrol](http://ddccontrol.sourceforge.net/index.html) tarball is missing a C++ file that the makefile calls for, but it refers to outdated hardware that I don't need anyway. **Can I simply remove the line from the makefile which requires this file and happily go on my way?** While running `make check`, I get the following error:

```
 - bruno():ddccontrol-0.4.2$ make check
Making check in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src'
Making check in lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src/lib'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src/lib'
Making check in ddccontrol
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src/ddccontrol'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src/ddccontrol'
Making check in gddccontrol
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src/gddccontrol'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src/gddccontrol'
Making check in ddcpci
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src/ddcpci'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `check'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src/ddcpci'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/src'
Making check in po
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/po'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../src/ddcpci/intel740.c', needed by `ddccontrol.pot'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/po'
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Consider this copy-and-paste from `/home/dotancohen/ddccontrol-0.4.2/po/Makefile`:

```
POTFILES = \
    ../src/ddccontrol/main.c \
    ../src/ddcpci/i2c-algo-bit.c \
    ../src/ddcpci/intel740.c \
    ../src/ddcpci/intel810.c \
    ../src/ddcpci/main.c \
    ../src/ddcpci/nvidia.c \
    ../src/ddcpci/radeon.c \
    ../src/gddccontrol/fspatterns.c \
    ../src/gddccontrol/gddccontrol.desktop.in \
    ../src/gddccontrol/gprofile.c \
    ../src/gddccontrol/main.c \
    ../src/gddccontrol/notebook.c \
    ../src/gnome-ddcc-applet/GNOME_ddcc-applet.server.in.in \
    ../src/gnome-ddcc-applet/GNOME_ddcc-applet.xml \
    ../src/gnome-ddcc-applet/ddcc-applet.c \
    ../src/lib/conf.c \
    ../src/lib/ddcci.c \
    ../src/lib/monitor_db.c
```

And consider these files that do exist:

```
 - bruno():ddccontrol-0.4.2$ ls -la src/ddcpci/
total 544
drwxrwxr-x 4 dotancohen dotancohen   4096 Nov 14 08:29 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 dotancohen dotancohen   4096 Nov 14 08:28 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dotancohen dotancohen 139344 Nov 14 08:29 ddcpci
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen   1900 Mar  9  2006 ddcpci.h
drwxrwxr-x 2 dotancohen dotancohen   4096 Nov 14 08:29 .deps
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  13597 Jun 15  2006 i2c-algo-bit.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen   2573 Jan 10  2005 i2c-algo-bit.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  92536 Nov 14 08:29 i2c-algo-bit.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen   8029 Apr  5  2006 intel810.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  27432 Nov 14 08:29 intel810.o
drwxrwxr-x 2 dotancohen dotancohen   4096 Nov 14 08:29 .libs
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen   8706 Mar  3  2006 main.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  47752 Nov 14 08:29 main.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  19944 Nov 14 08:28 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen    265 Mar  3  2006 Makefile.am
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  17227 Jul 27  2006 Makefile.in
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen   5647 Feb 14  2006 nvidia.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  21720 Nov 14 08:29 nvidia.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen   6982 Jul 11  2006 radeon.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  25416 Nov 14 08:29 radeon.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen   4832 Mar  3  2006 sis.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  24504 Nov 14 08:29 sis.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen   5814 Mar  3  2006 via.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dotancohen dotancohen  22200 Nov 14 08:29 via.o
```

Note that for `./configure` to succeed I did have to install a few packages:

```
sudo aptitude install libxml2-dev pciutils-dev libgtk2.0-dev
```

**Can I simply remove the line `../src/ddcpci/intel740.c \` from the makefile?**

Comment: Why the downvote? How can I improve the question? Even though I mention that I'm not a C++ programmer, I've made thorough efforts to investigate the issue and learn, and I've made that clear through the description of the issue. Furthermore, this question is not application-specific and could apply to others in a similar situation as well.

Comment: Don't agonize over it, it used to irk me but I've gotten used to unjustified downvotes over time. The one remark I could make is that there is nothing C++ specific to this question; if your Makefile was driving the production of a Latex document, it would not change anything; so maybe the C++ tag is just not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, Matthieu. I'm not worried about the rep, but I'm genuinely interested in improving this and future questions!

Comment: Indeed, the `po` directory name suggests that these inputs are used as `gettext` resources, not for their apparent primary purpose as C (not C++) source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing it. It will probably just mean that the functionality in that file (which you don't need any ways) will be missing.

Depending on how the makefile is made up, you might get an error from the linker when it can't find the object file for that module, but it will probably be handled automatically.

What's a worse risk however is that there is other code that is dependent on the code in that missing file; in that case the linker will report unresolved dependencies and to fix that you will have to modify the code, not just the makefile.